# error message "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Tags: r

Using R-studio on Windows 8 I am trying to use if to subset list of matrices using list of vectors with 1 number. Both list of matrices and list of vectors have same id. But when I run my code I am getting an error message: In addition:

```
Warning message: In if (true_only[id] > 0) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
  corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  directory<- c(getwd())
  id=1:332
  filenames <- list.files(pattern= '*.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
  tables<- lapply(filenames[id], read.csv, header = TRUE)
  complete_tables<- lapply(tables, na.omit, header = TRUE)
  s_n_set<- lapply(complete_tables[id], subset, select = c(sulfate, nitrate))
  s_n_set_vector<- lapply(s_n_set[id], as.matrix)
  true_only<- lapply(s_n_set_vector[id], nrow)
          if(true_only[id] > 0){
  corr<- lapply(s_n_set_vector[id], cor, use="complete.obs")
```

Comment: What does `true_only` look like after this error?

Comment: Try with `ifelse`  also the `true_only`  is a list., so perhaps `true_only <- sapply(s_n...,)`

Comment: true_only is a list of 332 vectors of 1 number, that reflect sum of complete measurements, after that warning it return complete list with  "0" at positions 272... and some other in different places. The problem is that as soon as id reach position with true_only=0 cor function stopped working and return only NULLs for all other id even sough they have numbers>0. So, frantically, I need to take each true_only value, compare it to "0" and if >"0" take matrix with same id and apply cor function.  I don't undestand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: It is not an error; only a warning. If you expected to create a vector then 'if' is the wrong fn. use ifelse

Comment: I tried ifelse instead of if It didn't help.

Comment: your program does not have proper opening and closings could you provide the full correct programm

Comment: The entire code looks like that: corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  directory<- c(getwd())
  id=1:332
  filenames <- list.files(pattern= '*.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
  tables<- lapply(filenames[id], read.csv, header = TRUE)
  complete_tables<- lapply(tables, na.omit, header = TRUE)
  s_n_set<- lapply(complete_tables[id], subset, select = c(sulfate, nitrate))
  s_n_set_vector<- lapply(s_n_set[id], as.matrix)
  true_only<- lapply(s_n_set_vector[id], nrow)
          if(true_only[id] > 0){
  corr<- lapply(s_n_set_vector[id], cor, use="complete.obs")
}
}  I just omitted closing.

Answer (score 1):

It is a warning message and not a error message .

1.The warning is in the **if** case and according to the warning **true_only[id]** has length greater than 1 that is it is a vector or list with more than one item

2.The **if** case only checks for only 1 item and therefore it is printing the warning that it will check with only the first item and not with the remaining items in  **true_only[id]**

**Modified code**

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
directory<- c(getwd())
id=1:332
filenames <- list.files(pattern= '*.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
tables<- lapply(filenames[id], read.csv, header = TRUE)
complete_tables<- lapply(tables, na.omit, header = TRUE)
s_n_set<- lapply(complete_tables[id], subset, select = c(sulfate, nitrate))
s_n_set_vector<- lapply(s_n_set[id], as.matrix)
true_only<- lapply(s_n_set_vector[id], nrow)
corr<-numeric(0)
for (i in range id){

      if(true_only[i] > 0){
      z<-matrix(unlist(s_n_set_vector[i]),ncol=2,byrow=F)
cor<- c(corr, cor(z[,1],z[,2],use="complete.obs"))
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want